# sinf() faster than sin() in <math.h>?

Tags: c, time, trigonometry

I was just wondering what would be faster for my program since im using sin and cos in a float variable so I decided to test it this way:

```
int c;
float a;
float b = 0.5;

/***********************/

glfwSetTime(0.0);
time = glfwGetTime();
printf("\n%f", time);

/***********************/

glfwSetTime(0.0);
a = sinf(b);
for (c = 0; c < 10000; c++)
    sinf(b);
time = glfwGetTime();
printf("\n%f, %f", time, a);

/***********************/

glfwSetTime(0.0);
a = sin(b);
for (c = 0; c < 10000; c++)
    sin(b);
time = glfwGetTime();
printf("\n%f, %f", time, a);

/***********************/

while (1);
```

And this is the output I'm getting:

```
0.000001
0.000505, 0.479426
0.000300, 0.479426
```

The question is the same, why using sin() with a float is faster than using the proper function sinf() ? Thanks !

Comment: Your compiler should optimize away both loops (and probably both sin calls too) if you turn on optimizations. If you don't, well, your test isn't really interesting - performance of non-optimized code is, well, not optimized.

Comment: It is not unusual for the machine or the C runtime to only support sin(double).  So you are paying extra to get the float converted to double and back :)  You can't omit details like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some implementations of `sinf` are just simple calls to `sin` with pre and post conversion to and from `float`. It may be your case.

For example see : http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/octave/gnulib-hg/lib/sinf.c